# Avoid exception causes to stop Mono.zip immediately

Tags: project-reactor

Is it possible to avoid that if one mono in mono.zip throws exception all other monos are stopping immediately? I want them to end normally and perhaps to handle the erroneous one by something like „.doOnError“ or „.continueOnError. Is that a way to go?

Regards
Bernado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `Mono.zipDelayError`. As you can understand from the method's name, it delays errors from the Monos. If several Monos error, their exceptions are combined.

If you have to get the combined result anyway, `zipDelayError` is not the solution. Use the `zip` operator and handle the error case with a fallback operator like `onErrorResume` or `retry` on the zipped Mono or any upstream one.

Comment: Hey, what about the results? Let’s say from 10 monos 5 will error and the other 5 will Termin as expected. The results are combined as the errors will be?

Comment: If one or more of the Monos terminates with an error, the zipped mono terminates with the combined exception. If you have to get the combined result anyway, zipDelayError is not the solution. Use the zip operator and handle the error case with a fallback operator like onErrorResume or retry on the zipped Mono or any upstream one.

Comment: see my answer above. some curios behavior.

Comment: Each time you change a mono with an operator, it creates and returns a new immutable instance as a result. In your case, `error.onErrorResume` returns a new mono but you do nothing with it. The result of `error.onErrorResume` should be passed into the zip.

Comment: yes you are right. the assignment was missing. :-) Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I stated that my question is answered but it is not yet. The following example states my case: some  mono will fail, but i want the result as the error too. i expected the follwoing code as to run to completion but it fails:

```
Mono<String> error = Mono.error(new RuntimeException());

    error = error.onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.just("hell0"));

    Mono<String> test = Mono.just("test");
    Mono<String> test1 = Mono.just("test1");
    Mono<String> test2 = Mono.just("test2");

    List<Mono<String>> monolist = new ArrayList<>();
    monolist.add(test);
    monolist.add(test1);
    monolist.add(test2);
    monolist.add(error);
    Mono<Long> zipDelayError = Mono.zipDelayError(monolist, arrayObj -> Arrays.stream(arrayObj).count());

    System.out.println(zipDelayError.block());
```

Comment: the assignment to the error mono was missing. now it is solved. :-)

Comment: also I think in general it will be good practice to do onErrorResume wherever is needed